# R: Pruning data.tree without altering

Tags: r, object, tree, pruning

In the **data.tree** package when one prunes a tree, it permanently alters the tree. This is problematic, as my data.tree takes a long time to generate, and I don't want to generate a new one everytime I have to do a new pruning.

Here I generate a data.tree

```
# Loading data and library
library(data.tree)
data(acme)

# Function to add cumulative costs to all nodes
Cost <- function(node) {
  result <- node$cost
  if(length(result) == 0) result <- sum(sapply(node$children, Cost))
  return (result)
}

# Adding costs and other data for my example
acme$Do(function(node) node$cost <- Cost(node), filterFun = isNotLeaf)
acme$IT$Outsource$AddChild("Tester Inc")
acme$IT$Outsource$`Tester Inc`$cost <- 10
print(acme, "p", "cost")
                          levelName    p    cost
1  Acme Inc.                          NA 4950000
2   ¦--Accounting                     NA 1500000
3   ¦   ¦--New Software             0.50 1000000
4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards 0.75  500000
5   ¦--Research                       NA 2750000
6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line         0.25 2000000
7   ¦   °--New Labs                 0.90  750000
8   °--IT                             NA  700000
9       ¦--Outsource                0.20  400000
10      ¦   °--Tester Inc             NA      10
11      ¦--Go agile                 0.05  250000
12      °--Switch to R              1.00   50000
```

Here I prune the tree.

```
# Pruner function
Pruner <- function(node) {
  cost <- node$cost
  cost_parent <- node$parent$cost
  if(cost < 2800000 & cost_parent > 2800000) {
    return(TRUE)
  } else {
    return(FALSE)
  }
}

# Pruning the tree
Prune(acme, function(node) Pruner(node))
print(acme, "p", "cost")
       levelName  p    cost
1 Acme Inc.      NA 4950000
2  ¦--Accounting NA 1500000
3  ¦--Research   NA 2750000
4  °--IT         NA  700000
```

I have tried to save my data.tree object in several ways, but they all end up generating HUGE files or by taking longer than it would to generate a new tree from the scratch.

```
# Saving object
save(acme, file = "acme.RData")
saveRDS(acme, "acme.rds")

# Generating a clone
acme_clone <- Clone(acme)
```

My next intuition was to see if I could just temporarily prune the tree using the Get function, as the data.tree documentation states that *There are two variations of this: temporary pruning, e.g. just for printing: This is the pruneFun parameter, e.g. in Get  side effect or permanent pruning, meaning that you modify your data.tree structure for good. This is achieved with the Prune method.*

It was not clear how to make this work as there were no examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some fiddeling around I finally tried the following, and made it work. There are no good examples, so I thought I would leave one here.

```
print(acme, "cost", pruneFun = function(node) Pruner(node)) 
       levelName    cost
1 Acme Inc.      4950000
2  ¦--Accounting 1500000
3  ¦--Research   2750000
4  °--IT          700000
```

Comment: Just for completeness: the following short form would also work: `print(acme, "cost", pruneFun = Pruner)`. I will also add an example to the documentation, as this is indeed missing.