# Pruning tree based on partial match of an attribute using data.tree in R

Tags: r, tree

I am trying to delete the children of a tree in a data.tree object based on partial matches of their names. like in the example below with the acme data.

I've tried this, following the pattern in the [tutorial page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#tree-creation)

```
> data(acme)
> acme$Do(function(node) node$trim <- grep('New', node$name))
> Prune(acme, function(node) node$trim == 1)
```

which gave this

```
> print(acme, 'trim')
                          levelName trim
1  Acme Inc.                          NA
2   ¦--Accounting                     NA
3   ¦   ¦--New Software                1
4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards    1
5   ¦--Research                       NA
6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line            1
7   ¦   °--New Labs                    1
8   °--IT                             NA
9       ¦--Outsource                  NA
10      ¦--Go agile                   NA
11      °--Switch to R                NA

> Prune(acme, function(node) node$trim == 1)
Error in if (!pruneFun(node$children[[i]])) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Then I tried something similar to what I saw in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052725/r-pruning-data-tree-without-altering), but still didn't work.

```
Pruner <- function(node) {
  a <- node$name
  b <- node$isLeaf
  if(b == T && grepl('New', a) == T) {
    return(TRUE)
  } else {
    return(FALSE)
  }
}
Prune(acme, function(node) Pruner(node))
```

which gives me this

```
print(acme)
levelName
1 Acme Inc.
```

Can someone please clarify what am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance, folks!